# Spark-SQL Command Line Using Hive Query against Remote Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to run a Spark-SQL (hive query) in Command Line against Remote spark cluster. But I am getting "Table not found" after connecting to Spark master.

This is what I am trying from `$SPARK_HOME/bin`:

```
./spark-sql --jars /.../calliope-hive-assembly-1.1.0-CTP-U2-2.jar \
    /../calliope-hive_2.10-1.1.0-CTP-U2.jar  --master spark://<<master_url>>:7277 \
    --executor-memory 1000M --total-executor-cores 2 " select count(*) *****"
```

This is what I am getting

> Error in query: Table not found:

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is the table existing in Hive.? If yes, please make sure you provide hive configurations to spark. Spark should understand the Hive meta store details, to get the metadata for a table..

Please check below link on understanding the integration. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

If this has already been taken care, let me know. There must be other issues if this is taken care.

Comment: Hi Srini,Thanks for the response. My scenario is that i am firing my query against my spark master and my table is in Cassandra. I don't have implicit hive installation in my env. Let me know how can i provide hive configurations to spark in this case. I am using Spark 1.6 against cassandra 3.0.4 version

Comment: Hi Srini,Thanks for the response. My scenario is that i am firing my query against my spark master and my table is in Cassandra. I don't have implicit hive installation in my env. Let me know how can i provide hive configurations to spark in this case. I am using Spark 1.6 against cassandra 3.0.4 version